# Copy files from find command output

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i am using below command to enlist the direcoties with name containing linuxS_x86 .

" find src/ -type d -name '*linuxS_x86*' "

it is giving correct output also.
Now i want to copy the files from the all the directories enlisted with above command .

Please help me out ..?

Answer (score 0):

use `find` with `-exec`

```
find src/ -type d -name 'linuxS_x86' -exec cp -rf {} <some destination> \;
```

`{}` is the placeholder to pass a single file name to `-exec` called command, and `\;` is to finish `-exec`.

---

or else you could use `ls` instead of `find`. Then pass found files to `xargs` to do `cp` command.

```
ls linuxS_x86/* | xargs -n 1 -I{} cp {} ./bbb
```